# how to get query result each day in one row using oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

I need to make SELECT in oracle SQL and the result each day in one row

I tried the following SELECT

```
select distinct admission_date ,
       SUBSTR(ADMISSION_DATE,7,2) as "admission day" , 
       case when nationality = 1 then count(distinct a.patient_no) end as "S" ,
       case when nationality > 1 then count(distinct a.patient_no) end as "NS" 
from inp_admission_history a , mr_files b
where admission_date between 20231201 and 20231230
and a.PATIENT_NO = b.PATIENT_NO 
group by admission_date ,  SUBSTR(ADMISSION_DATE,7,2) , nationality
order by admission_date
```

but the query result group each nationality in one row like this

```
admission_date    admission day   S   NS 
20231201             01           15
20231201             01               20
20231201             01               7
```

its group by nationality each day show in multiple rows

what I need show each day in one row only like this

```
admission_date    admission day   S   NS 
20231201             01           15  27
```

how can I do that please and thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post test case so I simplified the situation and used only one table; do the join yourself, but this is *how* to do it.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with history (admission_date, nationality, patient_no) as
  2    (select '20230113', 1, 1 from dual union all
  3     select '20230113', 1, 2 from dual union all
  4     select '20230113', 2, 3 from dual union all
  5     select '20230113', 3, 4 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select '20230114', 1, 1 from dual union all
  8     select '20230114', 3, 4 from dual union all
  9     select '20230114', 4, 5 from dual
 10    )
```

Query: conditional aggregation:

```
 11  select admission_date,
 12    substr(admission_date, 7, 2) as admission_day,
 13    sum(case when nationality = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as s,
 14    sum(case when nationality > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ns
 15  from history
 16  group by admission_date;

ADMISSION_DATE  ADMISSION_DAY            S         NS
--------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
20230113        13                       2          2
20230114        14                       1          2

SQL>
```

One more thing: why are you keeping admission **date** in a VARCHAR2 (or similar) column, as a **string**? That calls for problems. If possible, switch to `DATE` datatype.

Comment: Actually this is old design system admission date datatype number I will switch to date and I will create VIEW and collect all data and join in it then try thank you